# how to set the alpha in a barchart in lattice?

Tags: r, lattice

Consider this simple example:

```
tibble(time = c(1,2,3,4,5),
       var1 = c(2,2,2,2,1),
       var2 = c(2,1,1,4,5)) %>% 
  barchart(var1 + var2 ~ time, 
           data = ., 
           stack = TRUE,
           horiz = FALSE,
           par.settings = simpleTheme(col = c('red', 'blue'),
                                      fill = c('red', 'blue'),
                                      alpha = c(0.2)),
           auto.key = TRUE)
```

[image]

Despite my attempts, I was not able to set the `alpha` for the bars. They are way too bright! Is there a way to do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `rgb()` for your colors, the fourth argument is alpha:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lattice)
tibble(
     time = c(1,2,3,4,5),
     var1 = c(2,2,2,2,1),
     var2 = c(2,1,1,4,5)) %>% 
  barchart(var1 + var2 ~ time, data = ., 
    stack = TRUE, horiz = FALSE,
    par.settings = 
      simpleTheme(
        col = c(
          rgb(1,0,0,0.2), 
          rgb(0,0,1,0.2)),
        fill = c(
          rgb(1,0,0,0.2), 
          rgb(0,0,1,0.2))),
    auto.key = TRUE)
```

Comment: Handy tip: I often have to make a lot of figures so tend to make parameters like `theme_col1 <- rgb(0.2, 0.4, 0.8, 0.4)` which are then called for example as `col = theme_col1` allowing me to tweak all plots by editing just one parameter at the start of the script.

Answer (score 1):

The `panel.barchart` function for some reason completely ignores the `alpha=` parameter. @rg255's suggestion of changing the color is certainly the easiest way to fix this problem. You could also re-rewrite the panel function to actually use the `alpha=` option. It's a pretty messy function but I put the re-write in this gist: https://gist.github.com/MrFlick/d705d63075dd1d0c804be8e5543b9e72. If you load that function then you could just add

```
panel="panel.barchart.alpha"
```

to the call to `barchart()`. Unfortunately this messed up the auto key just a bit (it draws points rather than rectangles. But you could hack that back to the default by doing something like this

```
pp <- barchart(..., panel="panel.barchart.alpha")
pp$legend$top$args$points <- FALSE
pp$legend$top$args$rectangles <- TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

When specifying colours to R, you can use the hexadecimal format. In this format, you can add two numbers to the end that will relate to the degree of translucency you require. I'm not saying this is the best way of doing it, but it's how I achieve translucency in my core R plots.

e.g.

```
# Black points
plot(rnorm(10), rnorm(10), pch = 20, col = "#000000")

# Black points with 50% translucency
plot(rnorm(10), rnorm(10), pch = 20, col = "#00000050")
```